# Android build not rendering the signout control properly

Tags: android, build, codenameone

I'm having issue of missing signout button from the header toolbar in android devices. In simulator and apple device I do see the signout button but not on android tablet/phone. This wasn't the case before 3-4 days. Is there any change in the android build server that causing this issue. This is happening when more than one control in the toolbar. if the toolbar has one control to the right then it displays without any issue. Please let me know if anyone else have same issue.

Android Simulator Screenshot[image: Android Simulator]

Android Tablet Screenshot[image: Android Screenshot]

```
  public static void addSignout(Form f) {
        f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToRightBar("", FontImage.MATERIAL_LOCK, 6.5f, e -> {
            Server.instance.logout();
            new LoginForm().show();
        });
    }
```

Comment: How did you add the command? Are you using the toolbar API or something else? How did you style these areas? What do you see in the component inspector and with tablet skins in the simulator? Do you see anything in the device console in DDMS/logcat?

Comment: Shai, I have updated question with code I'm using for signout. I'm using the toolbar. I dont see error any where. Everything was working as usual. Simulator with tablet and android phone skin displays the signout image properly. Only after sending the debug build I don't see the Signout button/image  on Android Tablet and phone as well. Please advise.

Comment: Is there any change to toolbar that effects the behavior on android OS?

Comment: I don't think anything changed this week but it will with next weeks release. I might be mistaken though. I don't see the code?

Comment: Does team update the list of changes to build server on weekly basis or when ever it happens. Even before images used to miss in the debug builds and again it gets fixed in couple of days later. Please guide me.

Comment: I have added the toolbar code for reference. Please let me know.

Comment: also do a ```uiautomatorviewer``` check and verify that it's in the view hierarchy at run time. Is it the same problem on both devices? Could be different APIs or configurations

Comment: Problem does not exists on Simulator IOS/ Android/ phone/ tablets. Does not exist on iphone or iPad. Only exists on android devices both phones and Tablets. This problem does not occur if I have only one button on the right of the toolbar. Let's say I have signout without "Calendar" in the first image,display properly on android devices also.

Comment: With my understanding, when there is more than one button/image on the right of the toolbar debug build makes it run over the edge and not displaying the second  button. When I see closely, toolbar is extended and truncating "signout" control but the infinitecontainer  below the toolbar displays without getting truncated on android devices.

Comment: Shai, I have updated the question with code. Please let me know.

Comment: Did you do something like setScrollable on the toolbar or title area? I can't think of anything else that would trigger this. You'll need to isolate it to a standalone test case we can reproduce